# css("Right", posVar); does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

The Main objective here is to make an instant "jump" to the right. I don't want to use `.animate()`, because it makes a little "flashing" effect - because it is not instant. I think `.css()` will make an instant "jump" to the right, without flashing effect.

I don't know why this will not work.. Instead of using `.css()` I actually have to workaround this issue with `.animate`:

```
$("#gallery ul").animate({right: posVar},0);
```

Here is my actual code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   var posVar = 2838;        
   $('#gallery ul').css("right", posVar);
}, 300);
```

What's wrong with that?

CSS:

```
#gallery ul {
  display:block;
  position:relative;
  width:14000px; /*auto calculated from javascript */
}
```

Comment: What code are you using with `animate` to make it work? What CSS rules do you have applied? What `position` are you using?

Comment: Your using `#gallerie` in CSS, but `#gallery` in JS?

Comment: @Matt: Sorry - just a typo from my side, fixed. Problem still actual.

Comment: Did you try adding `px` to posVar?

Comment: If you are positioning your element by providing left and right co-ordinates then you should use absolute positioning. So,Try to use the position:absolute in css for changing the 'right' property.

Comment: @Salman A: im unsure how to write that, is that okay? - $('#gallery ul').css("right", posVar+'px'); -- btw This does not work.

Comment: "this will not work", what happens exactly? Are you sure the DOM is built? When does the code run?

Comment: All right, forget about adding `px`; seems like jQuery automatically adds it.

Comment: Please provide us with a full code, maybe even wrapped in `<script />` tags. I just tried both of your provided examples and they do work. Maybe it's your markup what's wrong.

Comment: only posibility i see is that you try to access the gallery-element while it's not yet loaded. Is your code inside a `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` ?

Comment: @Jules, that's exactly what I was thinking of, but if `.animate()` works, then it has to be.

Comment: P.S. I can imagine how much downvotes will come over this Q if it turns out that it's 'just a markup problem'. *laughing*

Comment: @Tom: true, given mtp-mike has put both pieces of code in the same place

Comment: - Provided full code - see the topic

Comment: Can a small HTML snippet be provided too ?

Comment: provided HTML code (scroll to #gallerie, and #thumbs) btw - its german code and i named it #gallerie instead of the english word #gallery ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>Css attributes:`left`, `right`, `top`, `down` will not work with `display:block` try `display:absolute` or `display:fixed`</strike>

I dont know what was on my mind when I wrote that answer. I mean to say.... you need `position:absolute` or `position:fixed` or `position:relative`

And I think the problem with your code is there is not "px" at the end...

I have fiddeled it, and here it is http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/8w6cS/

### **YOUR CODE IS WORKING HERE IS A PROOF**

http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/8w6cS/1/

---

**AND IF YOU TRYING TO MOVE YOUR `ul` to 2838px to the right Here is your solution**

http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/8w6cS/2/

Comment: there is no `display:absolute` or `display:fixed`. the fact that that `display` is `block` is irrelevant and is correct. Maybe you meant `position:absolute` or `position:fixed`, but even in that case having `position:relative` works with `left`, `right`, `top` and `down`

Comment: `display` has no such values as 'absolute' or 'fixed', that's `position` what you're talking about there. And `left`, `right`, `top`, `bottom` will work if `position` != 'static' no matter what `display` attribute is set.

Comment: @Starx: Your 3rd fiddle slaughtered millions. Badass

Comment: Just a question, what's the point of adding negative `right` if you can just use positive `left`?

Comment: @Tom: Starx used negative right. In my original script (i actual work on it) I use positive right.

Comment: @Tom, yes there is no difference between those two. I just tried to get his code working with least possible change he he.

Answer (score 4):

You mean `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`. It'll work with display block though.

I tried the following code, and it works:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var posVar = 100;        
    $('#gallery ul').css({ right: posVar + 'px' });
},300);
```

Comment: @Mike, maybe you should define a unit to the value of right? I.e. posVar = '2838 px';

Comment: That will definitely help. Drop the space before px though, like you have in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

It should work. Here’s a jsFiddle with your example code, working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/mathias/PjQBe/

Please provide us with more code.

Comment: P.S. `setTimeout()` blah-blah part, can be easily shortcutted to `$('#gallery ul').delay(300).css('right', posVar);`, looks much cleaner.

Comment: @Nick: Oh, really! My bad there, couldn't notice the 300ms delay, therefore thought it works that way too. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS as follows:

```
#gallery ul {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    right:0px; /*THIS WILL DO THE TRICK FOR JQUERY */
    width:14000px; /*auto calculated from javascript */
}
```

now your jQuery code will work!